# How to use drop-shadow on SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using an SVG on top of an image to make that specific part of the image clickable, and I am trying to make if you hover on the svg region the `drop-shadow` property changes colour.

This is the Image
[image]

And this is the code I have written

```
<div class="parent">
      <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 735 916">
        <image width="735" height="916" href={pathToImage}></image>{" "}
        <a href="/">
          <rect
            class="child"
            x="539"
            y="642"
            fill="#fff"
            opacity="0"
            width="166"
            height="174"
          ></rect>
        </a>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.child {
  transition: 0.4s;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten; /* work the best with the default black fill of svg shapes */
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
.child:hover {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(255, 162, 0, 0.876));
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.935));
}
```

I have used z-index to make sure the hover effect comes on top of the image. But this does not work and I am unable to figure out why.

I cannot put the `child` tag in `svg` tag because then the image is not responsive. As if you resize the image the image responds but the svg position on top remains intact.

How can I use the drop-effect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rectangle has `opacity="0"` so it is invisible.  Change that to `opacity="1"` and everything is fine.

Also, `z-index` hdoes not work with SVG elements.`

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.child {
  transition: 0.4s;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten; /* work the best with the default black fill of svg shapes */
  cursor: pointer;
}
.child:hover {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(255, 162, 0, 0.876));
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.935));
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 735 916">
    <image width="735" height="916" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PETyU.jpg"></image>
    <a href="/">
      <rect
        class="child"
        x="539"
        y="642"
        fill="#000"
        opacity="1"
        width="166"
        height="174"
      ></rect>
    </a>
  </svg>
</div>
```